# Prove $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n+i}{i}=\binom{2n+1}{n+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I'm trying to prove this algebraically: $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\dbinom{n+i}{i}=\dbinom{2n+1}{n+1}$$

Unfortunately I've been stuck for quite a while. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Turning $\dbinom{n+i}{i}$ to $\dbinom{n+i}{n}$
2. Turning $\dbinom{2n+1}{n+1}$ to $\dbinom{2n+1}{n}$
3. Converting binomial coefficients to factorial form and seeing if anything can be cancelled.
4. Writing the sum out by hand to see if there's anything that could be cancelled.

I end up being stuck in each of these ways, though. Any ideas? Is there an identity that can help me?

Comment: I'd recommend using induction to prove the result, although I'm sure it could be done another way.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mentioned that I tried induction too (a classmate gave me that hint). I got stuck trying to move the induction hypothesis from $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k}\dbinom{k+i}{i} = \dbinom{2k+1}{2k+1}$ to $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k+1}\dbinom{k+i+1}{i} = \dbinom{2k+3}{k+2}$ Specifically the $k+i+1$ part--had no idea how to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, hey! I just figured it out. Funny how simply posting the question allows you re-evaluate the problem differently...

So on Wikipedia apparently this is a thing (the recursive formula for computing the value of binomial coefficients): $$\dbinom{n}{k} = \dbinom{n-1}{k-1} + \dbinom{n-1}{k}$$

On the RHS of the equation we have (let's call this equation 1):

$$\dbinom{2n+1}{n+1} = \dbinom{2n}{n} + \dbinom{2n-1}{n} + \dbinom{2n-2}{n} + \cdots + \dbinom{n+1}{n} + \dbinom{2n-(n-1)}{n+1} $$
The last term $\dbinom{2n-(n-1)}{n+1}$ simplifies to $\dbinom{n+1}{n+1}$ or just 1.

Meanwhile on the LHS we have $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\dbinom{n+i}{i}$ which is also $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\dbinom{n+i}{n}$ because $\dbinom{n}{k} = \dbinom{n}{n-k}$.

Written out that is (let's call this equation 2):
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\dbinom{n+i}{n} = \dbinom{n}{n} + \dbinom{n+1}{n} + \dbinom{n+2}{n} + \cdots + \dbinom{2n}{n} $$

The first term $\dbinom{n}{n}$ simplifies to 1.

Hey, look at that.

In each written out sum there's a term in equation 1 and an equivalent in equation 2. And in each sum there's $n$ terms, so equation 1 definitely equals equation 2. I mean, the order of terms is flipped, but whatever. Yay!

Comment: Cool that you found it!

Comment: Okay... so tell me what I should do.

Comment: @Dr.MV This is the [subject of some debate.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11832/answering-your-own-question).  The OP didn't know the answer beforehand, but figured it out an hour after posting the question.  I think this is totally fine.

Comment: @SpamIAm The answer was posted roughly the same time that the question was identified as a duplicate.  So, given this question is indeed a duplicate, how does one justify the action?

Comment: @Dr.MV: Uh, no... yes, I ended up figuring out the answer about 10 minutes after posting the question, but it wasn't marked as a duplicate until a whole hour after I posted my (original) solution. My last edit was a good 15 minutes before I was accused of posting a duplicate, geez.

Comment: @jsluong That is fine.  What is the reason for your posting an answer?  It seems a bit curious.

Comment: Oh, well, I LaTeX my homework so I needed to type up the solution anyway. I figured other people could potentially benefit from the solution. This is a new account. I really am not trying to farm rep.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Use
$$
\binom{n+1+i}{i} - \binom{n+i}{i-1} = \binom{n+i}{i}
$$

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! This is the recursive formula rewritten, right? I'm trying to use it to see if I could solve this problem with another approach but, er, stuck again. Can I get another hint?

Comment: Yep, the same recursion you have in your answer, only with different values $k=i$ and $n \mapsto 1 + n + i$

Comment: Should be $\binom{n+i}{i+1}$ on the RHS.

Comment: @Dr.MV - indead, I have corrected it.